# How to read every 8 lines from a file and create nested array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, file-handling

I am trying to make a nested array for the EMI rates for my application. I have the bank names as well as interest values in a file. I want to make an array like key will be bank name and its interests for 3,6,12 etc. months. I want a multi dimensional array containing key as the bank name and the values for the months from 3-24 months. I am not sure how to proceed. Please help me.

**Array I want**

```
array(
    'ABC Bank'=>array(12,13,15),
    'ABC Bank2'=>array(12,13,15),
    'ABC Bank3'=>array(12,13,15),
    'ABC Bank4'=>array(12,13,15),
    'ABC Bank5'=>array(12,13,15),
)
```

**Emi rate file**

```
[abcbank1]
bankName = "ABC Bank"
month3 = 13.00
month6 = 13.00
month9 = 13.00
month12 = 12.00
month18 = 12.00
month24 =  12.00

[abcbank2]
bankName = "ABC Bank2"
month3 = 13.00
month6 = 13.00
month9 = 13.00
month12 = 13.00
month18 = 0
month24 = 0

[abcbank3]
bankName = "ABC Bank3"
month3 = 13.00
month6 = 13.00
month9 = 14.00
month12 = 14.00
month18 = 0
month24 = 0

[abcbank4]
bankName = "ABC Bank4"
month3 = 12.00
month6 = 12.00
month9 = 13.00
month12 = 13.00
month18 = 14.00
month24 = 15.00

[abcbank5]
bankName = "ABC Bank5"
month3 = 12.00
month6 = 12.00
month9 = 12.00
month12 = 12.00
month18 = 0
month24 = 0

[abcbank6]
bankName = "ABC Bank6"
month3 = 13.00
month6 = 13.00
month9 = 13.00
month12 = 13.00
month18 = 13.00
month24 = 13.00

[abcbank7]
bankName = "ABC Bank7"
month3 = 13.00
month6 = 13.00
month9 = 14.00
month12 = 14.00
month18 = 15.00
month24 = 15.00

[abcbank8]
bankName = "ABC Bank8"
month3 = 12.00
month6 = 12.00
month9 = 14.00
month12 = 14.00
month18 = 15.00
month24 = 15.00

[abcbank9]
bankName = "ABC Bank9"
month3 = 0
month6 = 16.00
month9 = 0
month12 = 18.00
month18 = 0
month24 = 18.00

[abcbank10]
bankName = "ABC Bank10"
month3 = 13.00
month6 = 13.00
month9 = 13.00
month12 = 13.00
month18 = 15.00
month24 = 15.00

[abcbank11]
bankName = "ABC Bank11"
month3 = 12.50
month6 = 12.50
month9 = 13.50
month12 = 13.50
month18 = 13.50
month24 = 0

[abcbank12]
bankName = "ABC Bank12"
month3 = 13.00
month6 = 13.00
month9 = 14.00
month12 = 14.00
month18 = 0
month24 = 0

[abcbank13]
bankName = "ABC Bank13"
month3 = 13.00
month6 = 13.00
month9 = 14.00
month12 = 14.00
month18 = 15.00
month24 = 15.00
```

**PHP Code**

```
$emi_rates_array = array_filter($emi_rates_array);
$bank_names = array();
$rates = array();
foreach($emi_rates_array as $ema){
    if (strpos($ema, 'bankName =') !== false) {
        $temp = explode("bankName =",$ema);
        if(count($temp)){
            $bank_names[] = $temp[1];
        }
    }                       
}
$new_bank_names = array();
foreach($bank_names as $bn){
    $temp = trim($bn);
    $bn_len = strlen($temp);
    $bn_val = substr($temp,1,$bn_len-1);
    $new_bank_names[] = $bn_val;
}

foreach($emi_rates_array as $ema2){
    if (strpos($ema2, 'month3 =') !== false) {
        $temp = explode("month3 =",$ema2);
        if(count($temp)){
            $rates[] = intval($temp[1]);
        }
    }
    if (strpos($ema2, 'month6 =') !== false) {
        $temp = explode("month6 =",$ema2);
        if(count($temp)){
            $rates[] = intval($temp[1]);
        }
    }
    if (strpos($ema2, 'month9 =') !== false) {
        $temp = explode("month9 =",$ema2);
        if(count($temp)){
            $rates[] = intval($temp[1]);
        }
    }
    if (strpos($ema2, 'month12 =') !== false) {
        $temp = explode("month12 =",$ema2);
        if(count($temp)){
            $rates[] = intval($temp[1]);
        }
    }
    if (strpos($ema2, 'month24 =') !== false) {
        $temp = explode("month24 =",$ema2);
        if(count($temp)){
            $rates[] = intval($temp[1]);
        }
    }
}

$rates = array_filter($rates);
$min_emi = null;
if(!empty($rates)){
    $min_emi_temp = min($rates);
    //$min_emi = ($price * $min_emi_temp)/100;
}
```

Comment: The array you're asking for doesn't appear to match the source data. e.g. it's not clear why bank 1 should have values of `12,13,15`, based on the contents of the file? Make the question clearer by making an effort to match the expected output to the input info, please, then there's no ambiguity. Also...you've written some code, so is there a specific problem with it? Don't expect us to wade through and figure it out, give us a clue to start off with - you already know what happens when you run it, so give us all the information please.

Comment: P.S. The file looks like an ini file, so https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php is probably going to make your life a lot easier and mean you don't even need most of the code you've provided. Try not to re-invent the wheel if you can help it!

Comment: https://3v4l.org/VCFEB … You’ll want to replace my json_decode used to provide the input data, with a call to `file` to get your file content read into an array of lines in one go.

Comment: @ADyson tthe parse_ini_file is working but I am only getting the last values not all the values. Can you suggest how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

As Per @ADyson suggestion I have used the `parse_ini_file` function to read the parameters of the ini file.

**Working Code**

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file(public_path('/includes/emiRate.ini'), true);
print_r($ini_array);
```